# Using 'as' in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a module that generates a csv file to feed data to a third party, but want to modify it to use for another company. The column names they want for the csv are different to the ones set up in the current module, such as Product Name instead of product__name.

An example of the sql in the original mod is:

```
$query = 'select
    p.products_id as uuid,
    t.type_name as product__type,
    d.products_name as product__name,
    d.products_description as product__description,
    d.products_url as product__url,
    d.products_viewed as product__viewed_count,
    p.products_quantity as product__quantity,
    p.products_model as product__model,
    p.products_image as product__image
    .....
```

I tried to change d.products_name as product__name, to d.products_name as Product Name, but it gives me an sql error.

Is there any easy solution to this without having to rewrite the whole module?

Comment: For most people it's very ovious to enclose the alias, but downvote?

Answer (score 3):

since you are using space for your identifier, you should quote them, like so:

```
  d.products_name as `Product Name`
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use backquotes to enclose your aliases.

```
d.products_name as `Product Name`
```

This is useful to output column names that are mysql keywords or column names with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d.products_name as 'Product Name',
```

When you want an alias with spacing, you have to treat it as a string.

```
d.products_name as 'Product Name',
```